# What does "a pop-up strike with a steep dive" mean?

Tags: terminology

In *Top Gun Maverick* (2022), Capt Pete trains squadrons:

> Capt Pete: It's the most difficult stage of the mission.
> It's a **pop-up strike with a steep dive**, requiring nothing less
> than two consecutive miracles. Two pairs of F-18s will fly
> in a welded wing formation.

What does "a pop-up strike with a steep dive" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are not military code words, it’s actually self explanatory if you just watch what the airplanes do:  They pop up, then go into a steep dive.

The pop-up was necessary because the ingress was done at low altitude to avoid radar detection.  The aircraft needed to rapidly gain altitude to both clear terrain, and to acquire the target.  The steep dive was also necessitated for delivering ordnance in that terrain.

Comment: ... and to add another point, unless using high drag ordnance, You cannot deliver high explosive weapons from low altitude because the weapon will impact and detonate directly below the plane, blowing yourself up as well as the target. Popping up and delivering from above 1000 AGL or higher, in a dive, is required in order to allow weapon time-of-flight (TOF), and the delivery aircraft dive recovery to create sufficient aircraft to weapon separation at impact. Generally, for Low drag High Explosive bombs, the weapon must fall for at least 6-8 secs or more to generate sufficient separation.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, good point, but I think that's a next level discussion to answer a question about advantages of a diving delivery.  I purposefully try not to over answer sometimes...

Comment: @Michale, yes, but in this case, the disadvantages of exposing yourself to AAA and radar guided SAMs vastly outweigh the advantages you mentioned. Unless by "...*optimized for delivering ordnance.*." you *meant* deconfliction with the frag pattern.... But as that is the most significant issue involved in the choice to perform a pop-up, it might be "*under*-answer-ing" *not* to mention it.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, except the OP was looking for a simple definition of the phrase, not pros and cons of the delivery method. (*reference their other questions*...)  But I removed "optimized" to preclude any debate over technique given the basic terminology scope of the question.

Comment: again, true, but if you're going to go beyond the "simple definition", and include the justification or reasons for performing the maneuver[s], then mentioning the most significant one of those reasons might be warranted.

Comment: Go ahead @CharlesBretana, I will upvote your answer.  I only dropped 25 lb blue death, it isn't my forte and I'm not interested in going deeper than what I have already said.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. It is correct. I just wanted to add the more important reason we did pop-up attacks as additional information. But thanks for the upvote.  From the early 70s to when I left the service, we practiced low altitude ingress (100- 300 AGL), to pop-up attacks and either low-angle-low drag, (LALD - dive angle less than 30 degrees) or dive bomb (dive angle 30 degrees or greater) weapons delivery attacks, to avoid frag damage.

Comment: When in multi-ship formations, attack geometries had to be carefully planned, and executed, to avoid other aircraft frag patterns as well, since the frag debris remained in the air for up to 30 secs, and created a dome shaped area above the impact point that was 3000 feet high and up to 6000 feet in diameter. Flying through this debris from your flight member's exploding ordnance, within 30 secs after weapon detonation, could also easily damage your aircraft.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, I was actually trying to suggest that you combine and edit your comments here into an answer of your own...

Comment: ahhh, yes, I mis-understood. If my thought is more of a tangent rather than direct response to an op's question, I often just make a comment instead of adding an answer.  At the risk of doing the exact opposite, let me say that I try to focus here on increasing general understanding of aviation issues, and not just to accumulate reputation points..  (I do not, however mean to imply that you were suggesting otherwise - I do appreciate your comments).

Comment: @CharlesBretana, no worries, I appreciate your comments, but it was the same tangentiality you noted that caused me to be reluctant to add your information to my answer.

Comment: I suspect we are back & forth on this way more than its worth.  If I implied otherwise, my apologies, but my initial intent was not to criticize your answer or imply that it was incomplete by not including the substance in my comment. Your answer was and is perfectly fine as is.  It was just to make that additional info available to readers ...